# Yii2 Write Custom Condition

Tags: yii2

I have something like this

```
$project = Project::find();
```

how can I write a custom

```
SELECT * FROM `Project` WHERE `personincharge` REGEXP "(^|,)2(,|$)"
```

Comment: Try `Project::find()->where('personincharge REGEXP "(^|,)2(,|$)"')`

Comment: how about how to use with addFilterWhere? @ineersa

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail Same condition format.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily by findBySql  this way

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `Project` WHERE `personincharge` REGEXP "(^|,)2(,|$)";';


$model = Project::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any plain sql query using Yii2 createcommand method as shown below:

```
use yii\db\Query;
$connection = \Yii::$app->db;

$model = $connection->createCommand('SSELECT * FROM `Project` WHERE `personincharge` REGEXP "(^|,)2(,|$)"');
$projects = $model->queryAll();
```